# Copying certain files between two SSD's is really slow

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, file-transfer

I have a couple ~1GB folders that I am copying from my 128GB Samsung 830 SSD to my 250GB Samsung 840 SSD (Brand new). It goes at around 250MB/s as expected for the first half, but then it stalls partway through. It will sit at the halfway point chugging along at 7MB/s.

I have tested other folders of similar sizes and they copy at the expected speeds. It seems like about 50% of my folders do this. Why is this happening? I have both SSD's optimized.

**Clarification:** The drives benched at 250MB/s READ. They both got around ~600MB/s write. I am using SATA3 6GB/s with AHCI enabled. It looks like when I copy the folders within a single drive, it goes blazing fast as expected. It is only when copying from one to the other that it goes really slow.

**Possibly Important Specs:**

- AMD FX-8320
- 16GB DDR3
- ASUS M5A97 MOBO

Comment: the 840 (non Pro) has slow write speeds because of the ugly TLC Flash.

Comment: It's probably slow when you're trying to copy a large number of small files.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Slower than the 830 yes, but I benched mine at 250MBs, and my 830 benched at 295MBs. That shouldn't make a difference because we are talking about extremely slow speeds.

Comment: Could there be a filesystem corruption with the source disk ?  If so, fsck it and repair the corruption.

Comment: tell us more about your hardware. 295MB/s sound like you only use SATA2.

Comment: @davidgo Note that this is a Windows 7 system, not UNIX or OSX.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am using both drives on SATA3 6GB/s with AHCI enabled.

Comment: copying folders on a drive to itself is **not** going to give you useful information.

Comment: @ryansworld10 - Ok, checkdisk then.

Comment: try newer AMD AHCI drivers: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/13-4_vista_win7_win8_32-64_sb.exe . Also try to switch to the Microsoft AHCI driver, maybe this helps.